# IOS 8: Real Time Sound Processing and Sound Pitching - OpenAL or another framework

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, real-time, openal

I'm trying to realize an app which plays a sequence of tones in a loop.
Actually, I use OpenAL and my experiences with such framework are positive, as I can perform a sound pitch also.

Here's the scenario:

1. load a short sound (3 seconds) from a CAF file
2. play that sound in a loop and perform a sound shift also.

This works well, provided that the tact rate isn't too high - I mean a time of more than 10 milliseconds per tone.

Anyhow, my NSTimer (which embeds my sound sequence to play) should be configurable - and as soon as my tact rate increases (I mean less than 10 ms per tone), the sound is no more echoed correctly - even some tones are dropped in an obvious random way.

It seems that real time sound processing becomes an issue.
I'm still a novice in IOS programming, but I believe that Apple sets a limit concerning time consumption and/or semaphore.

Now my questions:

1. OpenAL is written in C - until now, I didn't understand the whole code and philosophy behind that framework. Is there a possibility to resolve my above mentioned problem making some modifications - I mean setting flags/values or overwriting certain methods?
2. If not, do you know another IOS sound framework more appropriate for such kind of real time sound processing?

Many thanks in advance!
I know that it deals with a quite extraordinary and difficult problem - maybe s.o. of you has resolved a similar one? Just to emphasize: sound pitch must be guaranteed!

Answer (score 0):

It is not immediately clear from the explanation precisely what you're trying to achieve. Some code is expected.

However, your use of `NSTimer` to sequence audio playback is clearly problematic.  It is neither intended as a reliable nor a high resolution timer.

- `NSTimer` delivers events through a run-loop queue - probably your application's main queue - where they content with user interface events.
- As the main thread is not a real-time thread, it may not even be scheduled to run for some time.
- There may be quantisation effects on with the delay you requested, meaning your events effectively round to zero clock ticks and get scheduled immediately.
- Perioidic timers have deleterious effects on battery life.  iOS and MacOSX both take steps to reduce their impact by [timer coalescing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html)

The clock you should be using for sequencing events is the playback sample clock - which is available in the render handler of whatever framework you use.  As well as being reliable this is efficient as well, as the render handler will be running periodically anyway, and in a real-time thread.